# Toggle bootstrap navbar using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to hide navbar while clicking a button? I have tried the following, but it is not working.

```
<b:commandButton 
    value="New User" 
    onclick="$('.nav').toggle();"
    actionListener="#{loginController.openRegistrionPopup}"/>
```

Comment: are you seeing any browser console errors?

Comment: can you place the code on jsfiddle

Comment: I have checked. No console errors.

Comment: Yes. I will do that @Wazan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this. Working fine.

```
   <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <b:commandButton value="New User" look="link" ajax="true" 
                       actionListener="#{loginController.openRegistrionPopup}" 
                       immediate="true" size="xs" update="registration" />   
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
onclick="function(){$('.nav').toggle(); return false;}"
```

Comment: Small issue. Page is reloading after onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7697/)

```
 $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#nav").toggle("bounce");
        });
```